# I am trying to solve a challenge from jshero.net

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a challenge from jshero.net

> Write a function add that adds an element to the end of an array. However, the element should only be added if it is not already in the array.

Example: `add([1, 2], 3)` should return `[1, 2, 3]` and `add([1, 2], 2)` should return `[1, 2]`.

why didn't work this code ?

```
function add(Sarray, nosarray) {
  if (Sarray.indexOf(nosarray) > -1) {
    return Sarray;
  } else {
    return Sarray.push(nosarray);
}
```

but returns number `2`. I can't Understand it if .push(). The new element is passed as a parameter and is added to the end of the array. why in my code didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the reference for [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

Method adds element to the end of array and returns length of an array. You need to return array itself - not result of push method.

```
Sarray.push(nosarray);
return Sarray;
```

Comment: I think it is a bad practice to post code solution for learning exercises instead of a guidance on how to find such a solution themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```js
function add (Sarray, nosarray) {
  if (Sarray.indexOf(nosarray) > -1) { 
    return Sarray 
  } else {
    return Sarray.push(nosarray)
  }
}
```

The line `return Sarray.push(nosarray)` will add the `nosarray` as an element to $array. [Then, it will return the length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). So the if you assign the result of the function to a variable, the variable will be equal to 3 in your case. If you want the function to return the whole array, you would have to just execute `$array.push(nosarray)` and then return $array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay  then I understand my mistake thanks for everyone
right code this way

```
function add(Sarray, nosarray) {
 if (Sarray.indexOf(nosarray > -1 )) {
 return Sarray;
} else
 Sarray.push(nosarray);
return Sarray;

}
```